# NestJs validate array in request body

Tags: arrays, typescript, validation, nestjs, class-validator

I'm trying insert validation into PUT request.

**DTO's:**

```
export class SettingUpdateDto implements ISettingUpdate {
    @IsInt()
    @IsPositive()
    id: number;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    value: string;
}

export class SettingArrayUpdateDto {
    @Type(() => SettingUpdateDto)
    @ValidateNested({ each: true })
    items: SettingUpdateDto[];
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Put()
async updateItem(@Body() items: SettingArrayUpdateDto) {
    return await this.dataService.update(items);
}
```

**Servise**

```
async update(items: SettingArrayUpdateDto[]): Promise<Setting> {
    console.log("service data", items);
    return <Setting>{}; <SettingUpdateDto[]>items;
}
```

When i sent data, like this:

```
[
    {"id": -20, "value": {"name": "333"}},
    {"id": 21, "value": "2222222222222222"}
]
```

I received empty array. What am I doing wrong? Where is the mistake?

When i change settings in controller from SettingArrayUpdateDto to any, controller received original request data.

NestJs 6.10.14 version.

Answer (score 23):

To validate the array, create a dedicated class which contains a property that wraps the array, or use the `ParseArrayPipe`.

```
@Post()
createBulk(
  @Body(new ParseArrayPipe({ items: CreateUserDto }))
  createUserDtos: CreateUserDto[],
) {
  return 'This action adds new users';
}
```

Comment: `ParseArrayPipe` is from Nest.js v7, the author was looking for a solution in v6

Comment: Does it work for you? I'm having problems in my project running latest version of NestJS

Answer (score 1):

With the definition of the `SettingArrayUpdateDto` class, you need to send in a payload that matches it completely. That means your payload need to be

```
{
  "items": [
    {"id": -20, "value": {"name": "333"}},
    {"id": 21, "value": "2222222222222222"}
  ]
}
```

Because the `SettingArrayUpdateDto` has the `items` property which is of type `SettingUpdateDto[]`.